# Node.js packages reading moisture sensor: State never changes

Tags: sensor, node.js, rpio

I've written similar code in python that works as expected.

Using one of these moisture sensors: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ZR3B60I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZR3B60I)

The following code always prints "true"

```
const rpio = require('rpio'); 
rpio.open(12, rpio.INPUT);
console.log('Pin 12 is currently ' + (rpio.read(12) ? 'true' : 'false'));
```

Weather the sensor is submerged or not, regardless of the light on sensor (which I assumed was a visual HIGH or LOW) it will always come back true. When I remove the wire from the sensor, it will read false (as expected).

I've tried multiple node libraries all with the same result.

```
pi@pi-zer00:~ $ cat /etc/debian_version
9.4
pi@pi-zer00:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@pi-zer00:~ $  uname -a
Linux pi-zer00 4.14.52+ #1123 Wed Jun 27 17:05:32 BST 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Maybe wrong pin number? rpio uses the physical pin number, not the GPIO number.

Comment: I know it's the right pin because when I remove the jumper wire from the sensor, it changes the reading. I've also tried setting the pin using both the phys and GPIO numbers using 

`rpio.init({mapping: 'gpio'}); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a hardware one. Once I changed the sensor, it worked. Not sure why my last answer was marked worng. It's my question and it's working as expected....

Comment: Some moderator deleted my last answer......

Comment: Whoa! That is a bad experience for you. I am sorry this has happened to you. Please forgive us. I am glad your issue is resolved! :D